# JAXB / Jackson does not let to choose names for a HashSet items

Tags: java, spring, annotations, jaxb

Here we go in the parent entity the list is defined as a set:

```
@XmlElement(name = "picks")
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "picks")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "tour", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Pick> picks = new HashSet<Pick>();
```

And the child entity itself has the name defined:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "picks")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "pick")
@XmlRootElement(name = "pick")
public class Pick {
```

Yet the XML contains "picks" for both root and child elements!

```
<picks><picks><losPickId>2</losPickId><pickID>167</pickID>
```

Looks like annotations are not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try annotating `picks` with:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "picks")
@XmlElement(name = "pick")
```